# cv2.imshow only show partial image with big images

Tags: opencv

Image is too large for uploading, size is 2160*2880.

here is the code:

**cv.imshow** only show partial content of this image. but if I save image with **cv.imwrite** and open the saved image with an application. image have all the content.

Is this a bug or cv2 or I miss something?

import cv2

```
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
img = cv2.imread("0.png")
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite("xxx.png", img)
```

Comment: is the imshow window just too big for your screen? upload a screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` fix the window dimentions , so the image will fill the screen if too big

Try `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` which gives you the ability to change the window size.

after the save you maybe only use `imread` without `namedWindow`! (there isn't any other clear explanation)

**Suggestion**: You can use [matplotlib](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#using-matplotlib) for the show job, it has many parameters to use..

Comment: cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE give me the same result. the window is not resizable. I don't want change a lib because a possible limitation unless I am sure this can not be done with opencv.